# Problem writing array of doubles to a file

Tags: c, file-io, printf

i have a really big array of numbers with double precision...i tried to write it into a file using fprintf()...i need to write these numbers one in each line so i have done something like this.

```
if((fp2 = fopen("temp", "w")) == NULL) { perror("File cannot be opened"); exit(1); }

for(int k = 0; k < j; k++ )
{
fprintf(fp2, "%0.3lf\n", diff[k]);  
}
```

However, there is a problem that it writes the data upto certain number of lines after which i gives all zeroes. for example

```
3.040
0.700
-2.740
0.000
0.000
0.000
0.000
0.000
0.000
```

i really can't understand what could be the problem. why does it write all values as 0.000 when there are values in the array.

here is how diff was implemented if it helps.

```
            diff = (double *)malloc(fileSize);

        diff[0] = data[0];


        for(j = 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            diff[j] = data[j] - data[j-1];
        }
```

the values from a file were stored in data[]. i then calculated the difference of adjacent values in data[] into diff[] and write it back into another file. fileSize was the size of the original file. and i know for sure that all the values in diff[] are populated correctly.

Comment: How do you know there are some values? Did you use a breakpoint on `fprintf()` and actually check the contents of this array?

Comment: are you sure tehre are at least j elements inside diff?

Comment: Change the lowercase 'l' to an uppercase 'L' in the format specifier.

Comment: Can you show the source where `diff` is declared? And also can you show us the source where `j` is assigned a value?

Comment: yes i am sure, i checked it by writing printf("%0.3lf\n", diff[k]) into the console, it shows all the values.so i am pretty sure the data is there...and i know it has size upto j.

Comment: Also open your file at text '+wt'.

Comment: @roygbiv: why "+wt"? The 't' is not recognized by the Standard, it is a (redundant) extension provided by some compilers.

Comment: %lf is for long double, use %f for normal doubles

Comment: @quinmars: "%lf" is unrecognized for printf() and used for doubles in scanf(); "%f" is used for doubles in printf() (which has no format for float) and for floats in scanf()

Comment: @pmg - The main problem is probably the 'l' which should be a capital L which would interpret the argument as 'long double' instead of the lowercase 'l' as 'int'.  Perhaps it's best just to remove the 'l' altogether.

Comment: is it really a problem because of that?...i get all the correct values when doing printf() but when writing the same into a file with fprintf() the problem arises.

Comment: `%lf` is a compiler extension. We don't know what your compiler is or what extensions it provides. If you can write your code without relying on extensions, all the better.

Comment: @sfactor - Change it to "L" or remove the 'l', run it, and let me know?

Comment: yeah tried both approaches, it still writes those 0.000 values after a certain points.

Comment: +1 for showing the definition of `diff`, thank you. Now, what is `fileSize`, and is it related to `n`? Note that when you `malloc(fileSize)` you are allocating `fileSize` BYTES in memory. Each double takes 8 bytes (more or less depending on platform) so you will have `fileSize / 8` elements in your array. Are you SURE that `n` never exceeds the number of elements in your array?

Comment: @PP yes that was exactly the problem...thanks for pointing that out. it works now!!!

Comment: i was under the impression that since the data[] array had that definition, and diff[] had the same number of elements i could define it the same.

Comment: Note that you can write your file as binary, it is quite acceptable, just be aware that the line-ending may not be native to your platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding as an official answer after the comments:

You have the following line:

```
diff = (double *)malloc(fileSize);
```

Note that when you `malloc(fileSize)` you are allocating fileSize *bytes* in memory. Each double takes 8 bytes (more or less depending on platform) so you will have fileSize / 8 elements in your array. Are you SURE that n never exceeds the number of elements in your array?

The reason why your program *may* work correctly with `printf` and not with `fprintf` is that memory bugs are very very subtle. If you start using memory that you haven't allocated then things may be fine for a short period but go haywire when another part of the program quite legitimately decides to start using that piece of memory you're naughtily using already.

Answer (score 5):

The correct conversion specifier to print a `double` value is `%f`, not `%lf`.

C99 does not specify what `%lf` accepts. Your implementation may provide `%lf` as an extension for `long doubles` or something, but you need to match the type of the variable with the conversion specifier. Check the documentation for your compiler.

If you have `long doubles` the correct C99 conversion specifier is `%Lf`.

---

*Edit, after question was edited*

```
            for(j = 1; j < n; j++ )
            {
                    diff[i] = data[i] - data[i-1];
            }
```

The loop variable is `j`, the indexes for diff and data are `i`. Was this a copy/paste error, or is it your real problem? :)

---

*2nd edit*

Hmmm ... that `malloc(fileSize)` looks very, **very**, fishy.
Don't you know how many elements you need, based on the number of elements in the `data` array? Use that instead.

```
diff = malloc(number_of_elements_in_array_data * sizeof *diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be the fact that you have the array initialized to zero i.e. `0.0` via `memset` or similar. And when iterating the array, it pulled in the value in the offset which is zero (it could be you over-allocated/over estimated size of an array).

```
if((fp2 = fopen("temp", "wt")) == NULL) { 
   perror("File cannot be opened"); 
   exit(1); 
}

for(int k = 0; k < j; k++ )
{
if (diff[k] > 0.0) fprintf(fp2, "%0.3lf\n", diff[k]);      
}
```

I have added an extra logic to check if the value in the specified offset to the array is greater than zero, to put it into the file.

Another thing, when you specify the type of access mode in the `fopen(...)` function, it defaults to binary. Really it should be **t** to specify text mode, as shown above.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: fopen() defaults to text mode. The 't' in the mode argument is a (redundant) compiler extension -- it is not recognized by the C Standard.

Comment: @pmg: My bad! Thanks for the heads up! I'm old school... :P

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the first value, and the differences between successive values, Why bother with the difference array?  Why not do it the easy way?

```
fprintf(fp2, "%Lf\n", data[0]);
for(j = 1; j < n; j++ )
{
  fprintf(fp2, "%Lf\n", data[j] - data[j-1]);
}
```

As the other guy pointed out, your malloc() is probably bogus, and that's what's h0zing you.